CIFS storage timeout on Disk Move
I've just reinstalled the Proxmox, but before it I copied some of the disk of the existing machines to a NAS. Now I'm trying to move the disk to the new system.
It seem that Proxmox is waiting for something before actual moving, but it's unclear what. For a small disk, which is ~20Gb, it waits for about 10 minutes before starting an actual data copying. I've tried it a few times, and each time I see no traffic on the NAS side (i.e, no network traffic, not disk IO, etc) for the first 5-10 minutes. Then it starts copying, though the speed is about 1/3 of what it supposed to be.
But for a larger disk it takes forever. I waited for about 12 hours max, and a few times waited for an hour or two, and it never started actual copying. No traffic or requests on the NAS side.
I restarted the machine few times, checked all the network configurations, can access NAS from the command line, list and copy files, all looks fine. Even reinstalled Proxmox from scratch. Nothing helps.
What should I check to find out the reason of that?
I see in pvestatd the following:
pvestatd[1133]: unable to activate storage 'nas' - directory '/mnt/pve/nas' does not exist or is unreachable
pvestatd[1133]: got timeout

Just to clarify, this error repeats every minute.
And
# ls -l /mnt/pve/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Sep  7 21:55 nas

# ls -l /mnt/pve/nas
...TIMEOUT...

But once I stop the moving task, I'm getting no timeout. I.e. ls on that dir shows the files on the remote side if there is no copying task. I can see the files content, create and delete them. Also I can create VMs from ISO stored on that NAS. I.e., it's not auth or access rights problem.
Changing SMB versions (tried 2.0, 2.1, 3.11, in addition to the default 3.0) and remounting the storage doesn't change change anything.
What could be a possible reason?
